# Why does Maseches Shabbos focus so much on Hotza'ah/Carrying?

Tags: shabbat, talmud-gemara, mishna, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

There are 39 Melachos on Shabbos, yet by far the most discussed in the Masechta is Hotza'ah/Carrying.

Is there a reason why so much focus is placed on this one Melacha vs. all the others?

Comment: Is there any obvious reason why the simple answer of "there was more to say about it" isn't true?

Comment: @Rabbi the simple answer is it's the most relevant. Not everyone weaves but everyone carries all the time and it's really easy to accidentally forget and carry.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not familiar with any talmudic strategy to combat complacency by dedicating more ink. Also, do we carry more than we cook, or separate, or deal with mukza, or do things that could constitute building or final hammer blow?

Comment: @Rabbi yes we do (though cooking and muktza are close runners up and they indeed get a lot of Talmudic page time). And the strategy you are not (?) familiar with is to create more rabbinic fences and workarounds, all of which need recording and analyzing.

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Tosafos in the beginning of Maseches Shabbos 2a end of s.v. Yetzios and beginning of s.v. Pashat, hotzaah is a melacha garuah, a seemingly insignificant act.
That is why Chazzal felt the need to focus on it more than other melachos, and listed seemingly repetitive cases.